# Cannot chmod file on Openshift online v3 : Operation not permitted

Tags: django, openshift

I am migrating a Django application from Openshift v2 to v3 (In case you don't know, RedHat is shutting down v2 on September 30th, see: https://blog.openshift.com/migrate-to-v3-v2-eol/)

So, I am following this blog post to help me: https://blog.openshift.com/migrating-django-applications-openshift-3/ . I am new to all these Docker / Kubernetes concepts the new version is build upon.

I was able to make some progress : I managed to get a successful build of my app. Yet it crashes at deployment time:

`---> Running application from script (app.sh) ...
/usr/libexec/s2i/run: line 42: /opt/app-root/src/app.sh: Permission denied`

Indeed, app.sh has lost its x permission. I log into the failing container as debug and see it:

```
> oc debug dc/<my app>
> (app-root)sh-4.2$ ls -l /opt/app-root/src/app.sh 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 default root 127 Sep  6 21:20 /opt/app-root/src/app.sh
```

The blog posts states "Ensure that the app.sh file is executable by running chmod +x app.sh.", which I did on my local repo. Whatever, I want to do it again directly in the pod, but it doesn't work:

```
(app-root)sh-4.2$ chmod +x /opt/app-root/src/app.sh                             
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/opt/app-root/src/app.sh’: Operation not permitted
```

So, how can I set the x permission to app.sh ? Thank you

Comment: Hi, have you tried setting the +x permission on app.sh before uploading it to OpenShift?

Comment: yes I did : I set the +x on my local folder, then push it to github. The docker image is built directly from the github repository. I guess the +x is lost somewhere in between

Comment: What do you get when you run ``ls -las app.sh`` locally? If you check out your repository in to a clean directory, what is it there? The execute permissions can't be getting pushed up into GitHub properly. You also need to ensure that permissions aren't such that execute is only for just user. Some versions of the Python S2I builder may not copy execute permissions to group, as will be necessary, so group didn't have execute permissions already on ``app.sh`` you may have an issue depending on what versions of the Python S2I builder is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking into more details, any S2I builder image will gladly use your custom supplied `run` script to start the application in an alternative way.

Create `.s2i/bin/` (mind the dot) in your source code directory, place the `run` script into it and rebuild the app in OpenShift - it will automatically use your custom `run` script upon deployment.

This is the preferred way of starting applications using custom commands in OpenShift.

Regarding your immediate problem, there is a very simple reason why you can not change the permissions of the script: you were trying to modify the permissions in the deployed pod, and not the builder pod. Deployed pods run using different UIDs, usually somewhere in the range of 100000000, and definitely do not match the file ownership as generated by the build. Hence permission denied.

The root cause of your problem (`app.sh` losing executable permissions) must be in the way the build process installs those files, and indeed looking at the `/usr/libexec/s2i/assemble` script in the base image does seem to reveal the culprit. The last two lines are:

```
# set permissions for any installed artifacts
fix-permissions /opt/app-root
```

If you wanted to change this part of the build instead of using a custom `run` script, I suggest you then create `.s2i/bin/assemble` in your project's source code and make it look sort of like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running stock build:"
${STI_SCRIPTS_PATH}/assemble
echo "Fixing the mess:"
chmod 755 /opt/app-root/src/app.sh
```

This will fix whatever the stock build process does to file permissions, and will do it using the same UID as the rest of the build, so file ownership shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thank for pointing me into the right direction. I added a customized assemble script and it fixed the chmod issue. Now my container can starts and I can move forward, thanks a lot.

Comment: Neither a custom ``run`` script or ``assemble`` script should be required, and overriding ``run`` is the not the preferred way of starting an application. The preferred way with the Python S2I builder is using ``app.sh``. Leaving the original ``run`` script alone and using ``app.sh`` ensures that any custom steps in the original ``run`` script needed to set up the environment correctly are still run. You risk missing important setup steps that may be done now, or which are added later if you replace the original ``run`` script.

Comment: did you even look at the assemble sample?

Comment: This is a really great explanation of what happens in this s2i image and in openshift in general, thank you for that @GregaBremec. Graham Dumpelton certainly did not read your answer. Sorry for digging this thread but would you mind telling me why the permissions on the files in this folder are broken in the first place ? I find it weird that a script called "fix-permissions" doesn't do what it's made for. I currently have the same issue as OP and I'll do what you told him but I'm curious...

Answer (score 1):

as I stumbled upon this issue myself I've found a way to resolve it.
You have to make your file `app.sh` executable and push it in your repo as such.
If git does not track this modification as it did for me, you have to use: `git update-index --chmod=+x app.sh` for it to work.